# Add color picker in system.xml in serialized grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, system.xml, system-config, dynamic-rows

I want to assign the color code to a particular customer group by the system.xml file.
I have successfully created the grid, but I am facing difficulty adding the color picker in the color column of the config setting. For clarification see below image:

[image]

Let me know if anyone has done this functionality. Appreciate it in advance.